# Is there any alternative to handle multiple if , if else based on Element presences using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-refactoring

I was working in automating e2e automation cases.To increase the reusability we have used many if conditions inside a function and eventually script performance went down. Could anyone suggest me a alternative wayes to tackle this situation without compromising performance.

Eg ,

```
  public void Addvechicle()
    {
      If (iselementprsent(element 1)
       {
        // Do some action    1 

          If (iselementpresent(element 2) 
            {
              //Do some action2
            }

          If(iselementpresent (element 3 ) 
                  {
              // Do some action3
           }
    }
     else {
         If (iselementpresent (element10) 
          {
           // Do some action4
          }
         If else (iselementpresent 
           (element 11){
           // Do some action5
         }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop & Iterator:

First, define a list with elements that you know they might be there (this is a dummy example, you can create them also by using getWebElements if they have a common locator)

```
ArrayList<WebElement> elements= new ArrayList<WebElement>();
elements.add(vech1);
elements.add(vech2);
...
....
```

Then, use this approach:

```
Iterator<Integer> it = elements.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
  //perform desired logic 
  }
```

In this way you don't need to add so many conditions, and it should be faster.

Comment: I didn't get the suggestion. Perform desired logic may very for each condition..so we cannot keep inside while loop also

Comment: I didn't knew since is the same comment in all if blocks. If there are 2-4 different conditions, maybe you can nest an if-else block there

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have made update to question. We have to compromise on performance if we started using if else.

Comment: Got it, no problem. To be honest, since you always need to check if an element is visible then perform a specific action on it, I don't see any way in make this faster.